# Interpolated Calculated Field in Excel 2010 Pivot Tables

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, interpolation

I'm attempting to use pivot tables to interpolate a value from a large, multi variable table in excel. Is there any way to interpolate on a range within a Calculated Field? (Or any other good way to accieve this).

What I'm trying to do - 
I have the following table, and I'm trying to interpolate the Delta for each combination of Alpha and Beta at a Gamma of 5. With this simplified data, the answer would 15 for each set Alpha/Beta. In my real data, the Gammas and Deltas are not always nice even arrays, though they are sorted properly.

```
Alpha   Beta    Gamma   Delta
A       X        0      10
A       X       10      20
A       Y        0      10
A       Y       10      20
B       X        0      10
B       X       10      20
B       Y        0      10
B       Y       10      20
```

What I've tried
Formula -> Calculated Field -> Formula: = INTERP(5,Gamma,Delta)
*Note that INTERP is a custom linear interpolater. yv = INTERP(xv,x,y).

Excel won't let me do that, so I was wondering if there is a better way? I could obviously just manualy pull the interpolation arrays, but my data has ~50 Alphas and ~50 Betas, so that would take a very long time. I've tried automatically pulling the arrays with a combination of INDEX and MATCH (using array formulas), and it works. The only problem is that it becomes so slow that every time the cells recalculate, it ties up the program for ~30 seconds or so.

Any ideas would be appreciated. I'm thinking of using pivot tables, but a regular formula solution or VBA solution would work too.  Thanks!

Comment: How is the Pivot Table set up?  I'm not clear on how you are doing that Calculated Field.  Also regarding speed, the math here seems relatively simple (unless your custom formula is doing something not obvious), so it's not entirely clear why it is so slow.  I assume 50x50=2500 combinations/interpolations?  Even so, that should be manageable.  What did the `INDEX/MATCH` approach look like?  Finally, is your actual data arranged as above?  You should be able to compute it fairly quickly in that form, skipping every other row (or returning the same value).